# Espresso auto-granting location permission

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso, android-instrumentation

When I launch my Activity with  `androidx.test.core.app.launchActivity`it seems the Location permissions are automatically granted.
I've searched online and could only find threads where people wanted to find a way to grant those perm manually, I seem to have the opposite problem.
I need to test the loc perm request dialog, so this is a problem to me.

Does it ring a bell to you? Here is the very bare bone code I've been using:

```
import androidx.test.core.app.launchActivity
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class TestEspresso {

    @Test
    fun test() {
        launchActivity<Activity4Testing>()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().uiAutomation.executeShellCommand("pm revoke ${context.packageName} android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION")
    InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().uiAutomation.executeShellCommand("pm revoke ${context.packageName} android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION")
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Would suggest to [edit] the answer.

Answer (score 0):

When the activity is ready, like inside an `ActivityScenario` callback, you can do this

```
ActivityScenario.launch(YourActivity.class).onActivity(activity -> {
  InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation()
   .grantRuntimePermission(activity.getPackageName(), "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION");
  InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation()
   .grantRuntimePermission(activity.getPackageName(), "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION");
});
```

I suppose it is possible to do this whenever the activity is ready. You can find the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/UiAutomation#grantRuntimePermission(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))